# Group Chat Firebase Structure

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I successfully manage to create a one on one private chat using this structure

```
message {
          User1 {
                 User2 {
                         message1 {
                                     from: User1
                                     message: "Hi User One"
                                     seen: true
                                     time: (timeInMills)
                                     type: text
                                   }
                       }
                 }
           User2 {
                   User1 {
                           message1 {
                                     from: User1
                                     message: "Hi User One"
                                     seen: true
                                     time: (timeInMills)
                                     type: text
                                   }
                          }
                  }
         }
```

and now I'm planning to create a group chat that stores the same properties but unfornately I'm having a hard time to create a structure. Can someone give me an idea on creating a group chat structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Messages
  groupchat1
    userid
       message:hello
       time: (timeinMills)
       type: text
    userid1
        message: hello again!
        time (timeinMills)
        type: text
```

`groupchat1` will be the name of the chatting group, it will contain the users that are inside that chat and messaging each other. Then you can retrieve the messages using `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`

Comment: should I store all the private message and group chat in Messages node? or I will create a new child for private message and group message?

Comment: In the above answer it is a new node for the group chat only, and yes do another one for the private (1 to 1) chat